# Discord.js how to make collectors change things into uppercase

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make it so that when you run the message collector and when it awaits for a word such as "Lincoln," It changes it to uppercase. I tried to do it at the beginning of the code
(`let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();`), but it still doesn't receive it as uppercase, (so `lincoln` isn't accepted but `Lincoln` is) here is the full code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'verify',
  description: "help command",
  
  async execute(message,args, Discord, client) { 
    //Role IDs
    let Dixie = ['878755312159588462'];
    let Pacifica = ['878764278931410996']
    let Lincoln =['878764342462517298']
    let GOP = ['878722965972348938']
    let DEM = ['878722966660214844']
    let IND = ['878722965070544926']
    let PV = ['879068082772004864']
    
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    //First Embed
    var StateMenu = {
      color: 0x0099ff,
      title: 'Verification',
      author: {
        name: 'United States Mock Government',
        icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp',
        url: 'https://discord.gg/HcWtndSVEP',
      },
      image: {
        url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/878723133559939153/879040081107763280/States_List.png',
      },
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'State Menu',
          value: 'Dixie, Pacifica, Lincoln, \nType the name of the state that you want to join!)',
        },
        
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      
      footer: {
        text: `Type the name of the state that you want to join!\n If you would like to stop verification say **stop** or **cancel**`,
        icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp',
      },
    };
    //Second embed menu after you answer the first
    var PartyMenu = {
      color: 0x0099ff,
      title: 'Verification',
      author: {
        name: 'United States Mock Government',
        icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp',
        url: 'https://discord.gg/HcWtndSVEP',
      },
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'Party Menu',
          value: 'GOP (Republican Party)\nDEM (Democratic Party)\nIND (Independent/No Party)\n\ntype the abbreviation of the party you want to join, e.g. GOP',
        },
        
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      
      footer: {
        text: 'To remove a party do r(party abbreviation)',
        icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp',
      },
    };
    
    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id; 
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 105000 });
    
    //kollecter
    
    collector.on('collect', async msg=>{
      //roles u dixe if u type it
      if(msg.content === "Dixie" ){
        const arr = ['878755312159588462', '878764278931410996, 878764342462517298']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️ You already have a state')
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Dixie)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already have the state of ${msg.content}`)
        }  else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.add(Dixie)
            message.channel.send(`State of ${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
            message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
        }
      }
      //removes role dixie if u type dixie
      if(msg.content === "rDixie"){
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Dixie)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already have the state of ${msg.content}`)
        } else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.remove(Dixie)
            message.channel.send('State Removed✅');
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
          
        }
      }
      //role u pacifica
      if(msg.content === "Pacifica" ){
        const arr = ['878755312159588462', '878764278931410996, 878764342462517298']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have a state')
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Pacifica)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already have the state of ${msg.content}`)
        } else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.add(Pacifica)
            message.channel.send(`State of ${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
            message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
        }
      }
      //remov pacifca if u say rPacifica
      if(msg.content === "rPacifica"){
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Pacifica)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already have the state of ${msg.content}`)
        } else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.remove(Pacifica)
            message.channel.send('State Removed✅');
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
          
        }
      }
      //add role lincoln
      if(msg.content === "Lincoln" ){
        const arr = ['878755312159588462', '878764278931410996, 878764342462517298']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have a state')
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Lincoln)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already has a state`)
        }  else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.add(Lincoln)
            message.channel.send(`State of ${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
            message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
        }
      }
      //removes it if u say rLincoln
      if(msg.content === "rLincoln"){
        if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(Lincoln)) {
          message.channel.send(` Already have the state of ${msg.content}`)
        } else {
          try{
            message.member.roles.remove(Lincoln)
            message.channel.send('State Removed✅');
          } catch(error) {
            message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
            console.log(error)
          } 
          
        }
      }
      //adds GOP role
      if(msg.content === "DEM" ){
        const arr = ['878722965972348938', '878722966660214844', '878722965070544926']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have a party')
        try{
          message.member.roles.add(DEM)
          message.channel.send(`${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
          message.channel.send(`Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      //removes it if u say rGOP
      if(msg.content === "rGOP" ){
        try{
          message.member.roles.remove(GOP)
          message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      if(msg.content === "yes" ){
        try{
          message.member.roles.add(PV)
          message.channel.send(`Go to <#879068760374378566> to complete verification!`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      //adds role dem
      if(msg.content === "GOP" ){
        const arr = ['878722965972348938', '878722966660214844', '878722965070544926']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have a party')
        try{
          message.member.roles.add(GOP)
          message.channel.send(`${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
          message.channel.send(`Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      
      //removes it if u say rDEM
      if(msg.content === "rDEM" ){
        try{
          message.member.roles.remove(DEM)
          message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      
      
      //adds role IND
      if(msg.content === "IND" ){
        const arr = ['878722965972348938', '878722966660214844', '878722965070544926']
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have a party')
        try{
          message.member.roles.add(IND)
          message.channel.send(`${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
          message.channel.send(`Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      
      
      //removes it if u say rIND
      if(msg.content === "rIND" ){
        try{
          message.member.roles.remove(IND)
          message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      
      
      if(msg.content === "cancel" ){
        try{
          collector.stop()
          message.channel.send(`Verification Stopped✅`);
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
      if(msg.content === ".verify" ){
        try{
          collector.stop()
        } catch(error) {
          message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
          console.log(error)
        } 
      }
    }); 
    message.channel.send({ embed: StateMenu });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for your problem is simple really

Instead of putting it up here:

```js
let msg = msg.content.toUpperCase()
```

And collecting your messages here:

```js
collector.on("collect", async (msg) => {
    
    })
```

We can create avariable, such as `prompt` and do this

```js
collector.on("collect", async (msg) => {
    const prompt = msg.content.toLowerCase()
    })
```

I have done it to lower case, but you can do upper case if you want.

Thus the final code will look something like:

**NOTE:** If you want to change it to upper case all you have to do is `msg.content.toUpperCase()` and then change all the party names to ALL uppercase aswell, otherwise it will not work :D

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'verify',
  description: "help command",
  
  async execute(message,args, Discord, client) { 
        //Role IDs
        let Dixie = ["878755312159588462"];
        let Pacifica = ["878764278931410996"];
        let Lincoln = ["878764342462517298"];
        let GOP = ["878722965972348938"];
        let DEM = ["878722966660214844"];
        let IND = ["878722965070544926"];
        let PV = ["879068082772004864"];

        let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
        //First Embed
        var StateMenu = {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            title: "Verification",
            author: {
                name: "United States Mock Government",
                icon_url:
                    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp",
                url: "https://discord.gg/HcWtndSVEP",
            },
            image: {
                url: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/878723133559939153/879040081107763280/States_List.png",
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: "State Menu",
                    value: "Dixie, Pacifica, Lincoln, \nType the name of the state that you want to join!)",
                },
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),

            footer: {
                text: `Type the name of the state that you want to join!\n If you would like to stop verification say **stop** or **cancel**`,
                icon_url:
                    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp",
            },
        };
        //Second embed menu after you answer the first
        var PartyMenu = {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            title: "Verification",
            author: {
                name: "United States Mock Government",
                icon_url:
                    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp",
                url: "https://discord.gg/HcWtndSVEP",
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: "Party Menu",
                    value: "GOP (Republican Party)\nDEM (Democratic Party)\nIND (Independent/No Party)\n\ntype the abbreviation of the party you want to join, e.g. GOP",
                },
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),

            footer: {
                text: "To remove a party do r(party abbreviation)",
                icon_url:
                    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/875892431101517834/a2b34f1fd3ff52fdeb53fa4084ae058a.webp",
            },
        };

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
            time: 105000,
        });

        //kollecter

        collector.on("collect", async (msg) => {
            const prompt = msg.content.toLowerCase();

            //roles u dixe if u type it
            if (prompt === "dixie") {
                const arr = [
                    "878755312159588462",
                    "878764278931410996, 878764342462517298",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️ You already have a state");
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Dixie)) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        ` Already have the state of ${prompt}`
                    );
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.add(Dixie);
                        message.channel.send(`State of ${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                        message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //removes role dixie if u type dixie
            if (prompt === "rdixie") {
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Dixie)) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        ` Already have the state of ${prompt}`
                    );
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.remove(Dixie);
                        message.channel.send("State Removed✅");
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //role u pacifica
            if (prompt === "pacifica") {
                const arr = [
                    "878755312159588462",
                    "878764278931410996, 878764342462517298",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️You already have a state");
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Pacifica)) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        ` Already have the state of ${prompt}`
                    );
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.add(Pacifica);
                        message.channel.send(`State of ${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                        message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //remov pacifca if u say rPacifica
            if (prompt === "rpacifica") {
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Pacifica)) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        ` Already have the state of ${prompt}`
                    );
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.remove(Pacifica);
                        message.channel.send("State Removed✅");
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //add role lincoln
            if (prompt === "lincoln") {
                const arr = [
                    "878755312159588462",
                    "878764278931410996, 878764342462517298",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️You already have a state");
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Lincoln)) {
                    message.channel.send(` Already has a state`);
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.add(Lincoln);
                        message.channel.send(`State of ${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                        message.channel.send({ embed: PartyMenu });
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //removes it if u say rLincoln
            if (prompt === "rlincoln") {
                if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(Lincoln)) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        ` Already have the state of ${prompt}`
                    );
                } else {
                    try {
                        message.member.roles.remove(Lincoln);
                        message.channel.send("State Removed✅");
                    } catch (error) {
                        message.channel.send(
                            "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                        );
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
            //adds GOP role
            if (prompt === "dem") {
                const arr = [
                    "878722965972348938",
                    "878722966660214844",
                    "878722965070544926",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️You already have a party");
                try {
                    message.member.roles.add(DEM);
                    message.channel.send(`${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                    message.channel.send(
                        `Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            //removes it if u say rGOP
            if (prompt === "rgop") {
                try {
                    message.member.roles.remove(GOP);
                    message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            if (prompt === "yes") {
                try {
                    message.member.roles.add(PV);
                    message.channel.send(
                        `Go to <#879068760374378566> to complete verification!`
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            //adds role dem
            if (prompt === "gop") {
                const arr = [
                    "878722965972348938",
                    "878722966660214844",
                    "878722965070544926",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️You already have a party");
                try {
                    message.member.roles.add(GOP);
                    message.channel.send(`${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                    message.channel.send(
                        `Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }

            //removes it if u say rDEM
            if (prompt === "rdem") {
                try {
                    message.member.roles.remove(DEM);
                    message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }

            //adds role IND
            if (prompt === "ind") {
                const arr = [
                    "878722965972348938",
                    "878722966660214844",
                    "878722965070544926",
                ];
                if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => arr.includes(r.id)))
                    return message.channel.send("⚠️You already have a party");
                try {
                    message.member.roles.add(IND);
                    message.channel.send(`${prompt} Assigned✅`);
                    message.channel.send(
                        `Please type 'yes' to confirm changes`
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }

            //removes it if u say rIND
            if (prompt === "rind") {
                try {
                    message.member.roles.remove(IND);
                    message.channel.send(`Party Removed✅`);
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }

            if (prompt === "cancel") {
                try {
                    collector.stop();
                    message.channel.send(`Verification Stopped✅`);
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            if (prompt === ".verify") {
                try {
                    collector.stop();
                } catch (error) {
                    message.channel.send(
                        "⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator."
                    );
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        });

        message.channel.send({ embed: StateMenu });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make your code accept inputs, case-insensitive, you can make the string upper or lower case. Note that [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and `toLowerCase()` will make **all** characters upper/lower case.

```js
const content = data.toUpperCase();

switch(content) {
  case "EXAMPLE1":
    break;
  case "SOMETHING ELSE":
    break;
}
```

Example in your code:

```js
collector.on("collect", async (msg) => {
  // make everything upper case!
  const content = msg.content.toUpperCase();
  switch (content) {
    case "DIXIE": {
      // code
      break;
    }
    case "RDIXIE": {
      // more code
      break;
    }
    // etc.
  }
});
```

When doing this, be careful to ensure that your cases or if statements are using the correct upper/lower casing.